# Some tags give error: "redirected you too many times. try clearing your cookies"

Tags: wordpress

I am using Wordpress but face some problem on my tags. My some tags are given error "redirected you too many times. try clearing your cookies" not for every tag only for some tag like
https://www.engineerbabu.com/blog/tag/mobile-application/
[image: Error Screenshot]

and other tags are working properly 
https://www.engineerbabu.com/blog/tag/mobile-app-developer/
[image: Working Tag Screenshot]

Comment: have you tried to rebuild htaccess via  wp-admin->settings->permalinks->save ? if not, do it, and test the website in incognito browser.

Comment: Yes, I have checked,
I am using post Name and URL is correct.

but still some tags are working and some not working.